# VS2012 Annoyance - The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, build

All,

I don't know if this has just started happening in VS2012.  I've not seen it happen in VS2010 or previous versions.

I have a solution in VS2012 with a number of my own custom projects.  The main project is a SharePoint 2010 project.  This references a number of class library projects which are used in the SharePoint project.

I can build solution and everything compiles fine.  As soon as I start the solution the following errors are encountered for the same two projects in the solution:

The type or namespace name 'XXX' does not exist in the namespace 'YYYY' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I can get round this by building anyone of the projects the error occurs in and then I can start the solution to run up in SharePoint.

I don't know if this is specifically related to a SharePoint project or if others get it in their solutions.  It is just a bit of a pain having to do this.  It does not happen all of the time.  It just seems intermittent.

I am not making any changes to the referenced projects - only the main project.

Cleaning and building the solution does not resolve this either.  I need to manually build one of the offending projects.  All projects are set to build within Configuration Manager - and the main project is set to Deploy - which all looks correct.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

Andez

Comment: Sounds more like an IntelliSense parse error than a build error.  Check if all the projects target the same .NET framework version and do not use the Client Profile.  If you cannot change these projects then there of course isn't much you can do about that.

Comment: Hi Hans, It does not let me Run/Debug the solution - would Intellisense cause this?  All of the projects are set to use .NET 3.5, however I do have a reference to an x86 component in the Warnings:  There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "OSIsoft.PISDK, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3309f0734ba2805, processorArchitecture=x86", "AMD64".

Comment: I've just run into this as well. In my case rebuilding doesn't work. At my wit's end.

Comment: Same here.  It's something buggy in VS2012.  Only happens with C# projects, and even after rebuilding the damned squiggly lines come right back if you switch to another source file.

Answer (score 1):

The same behavior (as the poster describes) does occur with x64 builds for me.

My workaround is to switch to Any CPU (in the Configuration Manager: Active Solution Platform) . It may sound awful, but at least I can continue working on my project.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when the referred project/dlls pointing another .net frameworks. double check the project properties.